# Template Routes help and tutorial

Tags: template-routes

I read the EE Template Routes documentation, no have concrete tutorials and examples. It's hard to understand how to use it.

Does someone have a simple and concrete example ??

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can start from this [Mike Boyink's tutorial](http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/introduction-to-template-routes-for-expressionengine) it is very clear and help me to understand better templates route

Comment: Barbara, thanks for the link. Really it help to understand about the templates route. Would be nice a complete documentation with concretes examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mike Boyink's website and other tutorials are no longer up. The website has been shut down.